# Stopping UiWebView with a button

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, webview

Now that my project automatically reloads (with help form someone on this site :D ) how could i get another but to stop reloading?
this is what i have:

```
-(IBAction)SendGPSData:(id)sender {
    NSURL *myURL =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.uk"];//<<change this!!!
    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [myWebView2 loadRequest:myRequest];
        [myWebView2 reload];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(WebViewLoad:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(IBAction)stop:(id)sender {

//what do i put here to stop it reloading?

}

-(void)WebViewLoad:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
    [myWebView2 reload];

}
```

dont like asking another question so soon but im a total beginner to Xcode so any help will be great :)

Iv tried the myWebView stop loading;
but the original seems to override this :(

Answer (score 0):

You can stop like this:

```
-(IBAction)stop:(id)sender {

[webView stopLoading];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to stop the timer.  So you do:

```
NSTimer* reloadTimer;  // Put this in your class.

reloadTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(WebViewLoad:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(IBAction)stop:(id)sender
{
    [reloadTimer invalidate];
    reloadTimer = nil;   // Prevents crash, when this method is called twice:
                         // reloadTimer is released when you call invalidate,
                         // so next time invalidate would be called on non-existing
                         // object -> crash.

    [myWebView2 stopLoading];
}
```

It may make sense to put the code that starts/creates the timer in a separate method, so that you can use it restart the reloading again.